# Bound script breaking when file it's bound to is copied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two bound scripts in a template I am replicating hundreds of times. The scripts are easy and small. They work fine in the initial template, but when I copy the file dozens/hundreds of times, it breaks 50% of the time and I get this error when I try to run them from the new file:

> Server error occurred. Please try saving the project again. (line 0).

Saving the project again isn't working.

Why does my script break when I right click/make a copy of a Google Sheets, and how I can stop it?

Comment: Don't know what your script is doing, but I found two issues with similar issues already reported to Google.

[Issue 1](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3569), [Issue 2](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5348).

You should probably star one of those or report your issue there as a separate one. However, what's the frequency with which you're creating copies?

Comment: If you are coping the file `dozens/hundreds of times`, turning your [script into an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) would probably save you a ton of trouble.

Comment: @pointNclick I copy once per week or so

Comment: As well as using an add-on, using GAS libraries [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries] might also help avoid duplicating lots of code. As would publishing the core of the app as a WebApp, and then calling the WebApp from the bound script. It may not completely solve the problem, as it does sound like a bug, but it might reduce the amount of time you see it and is good practice anyway.